# Can I safely use observeForever in my repository?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I follow the architecture pattern laid out in [Android Room with a View - Kotlin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0). My app displays N stacks and every of those stacks can be displayed with a closed cover or an open cover. The number of stacks can change at run time. The information about whether or not the cover is closed is not permanent and I have to react in the UI when it changes. I therefore thought about making it a LiveData object.

```
class ContentRepository(private  val contentDao: ContentDao) {
    val allStacks : LiveData<List<Stack>> = contentDao.getStacks()
    val showCover = HashMap<Int, LiveData<Boolean>>()

    init {
        allStacks.observeForever { stacks ->
            stacks.filter { !showCover.containsKey(it.number) }
                .map { showCover.put(
                    it.number,
                    MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)) }
        }
    }
}
```

Given that I don't have access to a LifeCycleOwner from within the repository, can I use observeForever here, or will it result in data leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Repository is meant to have the same life cycle as the application and only one instance of it is created it should be fine. If not, you will end up leaking the repositories.

You should consider using the `map` extension function of `LiveData` to map the content into a new `LiveData` without the need of observing it, and instead of exposing a `Map<Int, LiveData<Boolean>>` exposing a `LiveData<Map<Int, Boolean>>` I don't know if this solution will work for your usecase. But if you can find a way to use the `map` function instead of observing forever it will make your code more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Use should Transformations in such case. For example:

```
val allStacks : LiveData<List<Stack>> = contentDao.getStacks()
private val mShowCover = HashMap<Int, Boolean>()

val showCover = Transformations.map(allStacks) { stacks ->
    stacks.filter { !mShowCover.containsKey(it.number) }
                .map { mShowCover.put(
                        it.number,
                        false
                      ) 
                    }

    mShowCover 
}
```

Comment: If I make the variable private it misses the point. I'm not seeing how I could switch it to true with your code and have that switch be reflected in the UI.

Comment: First of all, a repository should only contain business models. I don't know exactly what your use case is, but if your view changes cover visibility you probably should move the showCover variable to ViewModel and do the transformation there. View notifies ViewModel with method like model.onOpenCoverClick(coverNum) and observes showCover.